# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Fragment

Tags: xamarin.android

I've got the following error with my Button:**Object reference not set to an instance of an object** Error is showing when i try to assign Click to my button.

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Tablayout3, container, false);

        View content = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.alertdialogCustom,null);


        alertDialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this.Activity).Create();

        alertDialog.SetView(content);


        Button buttonX = this.Activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.timepickerZamkniecie);
        Button buttonO = this.Activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.timepickerOtwarcie);

        buttonX.Click += delegate { };

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Button buttonX = this.Activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.timepickerZamkniecie);

Actually , you should invoked `view.FindViewById` in Fragment to get the control .

Use the following line instead of it

```
Button buttonX = v.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.timepickerZamkniecie);
```